# Is it possible to connect leaderboard of two apps in google play game services?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have a free version of game in play store and i am planning to update to paid version(package name will change) with more features, right now my free version has a leaderboard integrated into it, and i want my paid application to follow same leaderboard is it possible for sharing leaderboard between two apps. or its better if i go with in app purchase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for sharing leaderboard between two apps?

Absolutely. You can use the same leaderboard(s) and achievements.

In your *Google Developer Account*, under the *Game Services* link, you setup a Game.  (with all the Leader boards and Achievements you want to have available for any/all versions of your Game)

[image]

Then, under each Game, you then get to link Apps up to the Game.  The linked apps can be up to 20 applications in total, covering Android/iOS/Web applications. Any of those can be free or paid.. .and you could have multiple leader boards, with each App deciding which leader board(s) to pick from and to display/update.  If you want them to all share the same leader board(s), that's fine.. .if for some reason you want to have a leaderboard for each specific platform/app version that would be fine too, as well as maybe having an overall leaderboard for All of your different Apps.  (from below, you can see I have three different apps linked to the dice game, and all three are android, and all are ready to publish, and they all use the same leaderboards/achievements and use the Room services)

[image]

The Google Leaderboard Tutorial doesn't cover this quite to the detail that you were probably looking for, and hopefully this shows how to setup multiple apps/platforms for one game a little clearer and with more confidence that it does do exactly what you are looking at implementing.

> It's better if i go with in app purchase ?

I believe that depends. Usually, putting them separately may lead to a lot of extra work to get both to work together in the future.

Comment: between i dont want to create my own leaderboard cloud service, i want to use google leaderboard from google play services, is it possible in that case ?